# Webfont not loading on page load on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webfonts

I'm having an issue with loading a WebFont on Chrome version "48.0.2564.82 m (64-bit)".

The issue is that the webfont is not being applied when I load the page or navigate to the page via any means other than using the refresh function.

This is the segment of code in my CSS file where I load in and set the font:

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300italic,700);

body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #444444;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, arial;
}
```

I've made a gfycat of the issue here:
https://gfycat.com/UnfoldedAlarmingFoxhound

Any clues?

Comment: Do you have the import line at the very top of the CSS file? Also I am assuming you have tested it without part of the url being commented out?

Comment: Have you tried including the font in head section - method ???

Comment: I'm pretty sure `@import`'s url needs to be a string.

Comment: @Sivadass I've tried that as well however I still have the same problem.

Comment: Is the web page running on a server/localhost, or you open the html directly from a folder? Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: @Pangloss I'm running the website on a public server on DigitalOcean. There aren't any related errors in the logs.

Comment: Inspect body element in the developer tools, and check whether the font-family being overridden by other rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue and they fixed it for version 49.0.2623.13. try it with canary.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=579912&q=font%20os%3DWindows&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you need to make sure the @import is at the top of the CSS file, in addition to this you have your URL commented out, not wrapped in a quotes and without 'http' at the start.

What it should be

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300italic,700);
```

Try this -

```
body {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: My import is already at the top of my CSS file and adding the protocol and wrapping the URL in quotes does not work either.

Comment: I have just updated it, try it again and see if it works

Comment: Just tested it myself and it works for me, https://jsfiddle.net/u3v8zj0h/, if you still cannot get it to work there could perhaps be other CSS which is interfering with it.

Comment: It seems to work via jsfiddle. However, I can't find any conflicting styles in my stylesheet which would cause it not to work on my website. The font loads fine on other browsers such as FireFox however.

Comment: Give this a go, apparently chrome is know not to render fonts sometimes. I have put the code above.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't fix the problem either.